# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am trying to follow the instructions on https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android-vm.html to create kivy android applications. I installed Kivy Buildozer VM and was following instructions on the Readme file. Created the buildozer.spec file using `buildozer init` command but `buildozer android debug` is failing with following output

```
   (cd /media/sf_virtual_box/organizer/2nd_vid_tute/step07_padding/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin; ln python2.7 python)
    ln: failed to create hard link ‘python’ => ‘python2.7’: Operation not permitted
    make: *** [bininstall] Error 1
    Leaving ARM environment
    cp: cannot stat ‘build/lib.*-2.7/_ctypes*.so’: No such file or directory
    # Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "myapp1"
    # 
    # Buildozer failed to execute the last command
    # The error might be hidden in the log above this error
    # Please read the full log, and search for it before
    # raising an issue with buildozer itself.
    # In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This will occur if the kivy project on the Virtual Machine is in a shared folder with the host machine.
(In my case the host is Windows.)

If this is the case, try copying the kivy project folder to /home/, and make sure this is not shared.
Make sure the permissions are set to 777.